# How do I `tee` output to multiple piped commands with zsh on macOS?

Tags: macos, zsh, tee

I am using the `tmutil status` command to give me the current TimeMachine backup status. It gives an output of the sort

```
% tmutil status
Backup session status:
{
    BackupPhase = Copying;
    ClientID = "com.apple.backupd";
    DateOfStateChange = "2022-11-21 11:23:03 +0000";
    DestinationID = "89E08126-7132-4D14-80B4-EFD45E8C5BFC";
    FirstBackup = 1;
    Progress =     {
        Percent = "0.1640944884974286";
        TimeRemaining = 65013;
        "_raw_Percent" = "0.1640944884974286";
        "_raw_totalBytes" = 488603537408;
        bytes = 80177147549;
        files = 159679;
        totalBytes = 488603537408;
        totalFiles = 3345928;
    };
    Running = 1;
    Stopping = 0;
}
```

This is not JSON, though it looks a bit like it.

I want to report on the Percent Complete and the Time Remaining.

I can get the Percent Complete with

```
tmutil status | grep "raw_Percent" | LC_NUMERIC="C" awk -F '"' '{print "Percent Complete: " ($4 * 100) "%"} '
```

and I can get the Time Remaining with

```
tmutil status | grep "TimeRemaining" | awk '{print "Time Remaining: " ($3/3600) " hours"} '
```

How can I run tmutil once (it seems to be a little expensive), and send the output to two `grep ... | awk ...` commands?

My understanding is that I could do

```
tmutil status | tee > (grep "raw_Percent" | LC_NUMERIC="C" awk -F '"' '{print "Percent Complete: " ($4 * 100) "%"} ') | (grep "TimeRemaining" | awk '{print "Time Remaining: " ($3/3600) " hours"} ')
```

with each command (pipes and all) in brackets.

But, instead, I get

```
zsh: no matches found: (grep raw_Percent | LC_NUMERIC=C awk -F " {print "Percent Complete: " ($4 * 100) "%"} )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to redirect the standard output of `tee` to a subshell. What you want are two separate *process* substitutions, `tee >(...) >(...)`. (Note the lack of a space between `>` and `(` in each case.)

As an aside, you don't need to use `grep` in either case; just let `awk` filter the lines.

```
tmutil status | 
  tee >(LC_NUMERIC="C" awk -F '"' '/raw_Percent/ {print "Percent Complete: " ($4 * 100) "%"} ') \
      >(awk '/TimeRemaining/ {print "Time Remaining: " ($3/3600) " hours"} ')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked for me, with the exception that `>(...) >(...)` also gave me the full output too. Using `>(...) |(...)` suppressed that for me. The lack of space is significant

Comment: I'm leaving this answer up for now, but I would strongly recommend using my other answer.

Comment: this worked for me ```tmutil status | tee >(awk -v CONVFMT='%.1f' -F '"' '/raw_Percent/ {print "Percent Complete: " ($4 * 100) "%"} ') |(awk -v CONVFMT='%.1f' '/TimeRemaining/ {print "Time Remaining: " ($3/3600) " hours"} ')```. I don't have `jq` on my machine (yet - I will look into it).

Comment: I only used `jq` as an example; you could use any language with a JSON library to parse the JSON, which should be safer and easier than trying to parse the output of `tmutil` directly.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of struggle, I figured out how to use `plutil` to convert the output of `tmutil` into JSON. (The trick is that the first line is just raw text and must be discarded, but the rest is the property-list format that `plutil` can parse.)

```
# Assuming the output shown in your question
% tmutil status | sed '1d' | plutil -convert -json -o - - | jq '.Progress| ._raw_Percent, .TimeRemaining'
0.1640944884974286
65013
```

This makes parsing more robust, and (with `jq`) provides simpler input to a single `awk` command, if you don't want to try your hand at producing the desired text in `jq` itself.

Though `zsh` can handle floating-point arithmetic itself, so you probably don't even need `awk`. For example,

```
% tmutil status | ... | { read pct; read tr; }
% print "Percent complete: $(( tr * 100 ))%"
Percent complete: 16.409448849742862%
```

Comment: `plutil` appears to have some other options for manipulating the property list, but they are not well documented and I don't have a newer version of `plutil` to experiment. (For various reasons, I'm still using macOS 10.15.)